# How can I print a pretty object diff in a Jest custom matcher?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm writing a custom Jest matcher to compare objects in some arbitrary way:

```
expect.extend({
  toTorgle(received, expected) {
    ...
    return {
      pass: false,
      message: () => "expect(received).toTorgle(expected):" + ???
    }
  }
})
```

How can I print a nice object diff between the two objects, like the one that I get with (built-in matcher) `expect(received).toEqual(expected)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Jest-Platform document](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-platform#jest-diff), you can use `jest-diff` to get a "pretty-printed" string illustrating the difference between the two arguments.

Your `message` function will become:

```
const { diff } = require('jest-diff'); // already available if Jest is installed

// ...

message: () => "expect(received).toTorgle(expected):" + diff(expected, received),
```

By default, the first argument to `diff()` is labelled `Expected` and the second is labelled `Received`. This can be changed by supplying Options as a third argument. See [the Options documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-diff#Options).

Answer (score 0):

Since [vitest](https://vitest.dev/) is getting traction over jest, it might be helpful sharing how to pretty print diff in vitest custom matcher.

In comparison to jest, it's not necessary to employ `jest-diff` package, because the custom matcher return type in vitest [supports the actual and expected objects](https://vitest.dev/guide/extending-matchers):

```
expect.extend({
  toTorgle(received, expected) {
    ...
    return {
      pass: false,
      message: () => 'expect(received).toTorgle(expected):',
      actual: received,
      expected,
    }
  }
});
```

Here's how the failing test output (with diff) will look like:

[image: Failing test output with pretty printed diff in vitest]